# vec.erase(vec.end()); Legal?

Tags: c++, stl, erase

Can sequential containers erase end?

In the standard it says:

```
a.erase(q) 
Requires: For vector and deque, T shall be
MoveAssignable.
Effects: Erases the element pointed to by q
```

It is not clear if `a.erase(a.end())` is a no-op or UB for sequential containers. Ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

§23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts]/p3 (emphasis mine):

> In Tables 100 and 101, `X` denotes a sequence container class, a
>   denotes `a` value of `X` containing elements of type `T`, [...], **`q`
>   denotes a valid dereferenceable const iterator to `a`**.

Table 100 is the sequence container requirements table containing `a.erase(q)`.

In other words, `a.erase(a.end())` is UB.

Comment: I was just looking at that, looks like you got it.

Answer (score 5):

If we use [this reference page for erase()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) :

> The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.

So, no - it is not valid.

Comment: It would be nice to see which part of the standard is cppreference.com referring to when it claims this.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan ageed, cppreference often includes notes which are not normative.

Answer (score 0):

From cplusplus.com: "An invalid position or range causes undefined behavior."